# C# Amazon Web Service - Get contents from an external bucket with paid access

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm running a code that returns the following error:

> Access Denied

When I try to get content using the S3 Browser, it displays an alert that access is paid, and then I can access the content. How do I setup my request to accept paid access?

```
string accessKey = "******";
string secretKey = "******";

AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com";

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, config);

ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
request.BucketName = "******";

ListObjectsResponse response = s3Client.ListObjects(request);
```

Alert form S3 Browser:

[image: Alert form S3 Browser]